# Can I start the minor work before the construction permit has been issued?

Tags: construction, permitting

I need to replace the ceiling in my kitchen from drop ceiling tiles to sheetrock. Will this be regarded as minor work? On the New Jersey state website (https://www.nj.gov/dca/divisions/codes/alerts/pdfs/OM_MW_03052018.pdf):
"Minor work requires a construction permit but allows work to begin before the permit has been issued once notice of the work has been given to the local code enforcement agency. The notice may be oral, written, or email."

So, once the contractor submits the application, can they start the work without waiting for the permit to be approved?

Will Jersey City adhere to this rule, or does JC have its own rule?

Comment: It's "ordinary maintenance" under the "Building" section. Read your document.

Comment: If your contractor is even the slightest bit reputable, he'll have worked with the building commission before and he'll know whether this A) requires a permit at all, and if it does B) if it's considered minor work or not. You're paying him, expect him to do _all_ of his job!